# Custom PowerShell Cmdlet does not accept Variables

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I have a custom PowerShell cmdlet that has the following attributes on one of the input properties.  The property is a get/set of type float . I want to be able to supply this property with either a float value or a variable.

```
[Parameter(
ValueFromPipeline=true,
ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true,
Mandatory = true)]
public float MyProperty
{
    get { return _myProp; }
    set { _myProp = value; }
}
```

Declaring and assigning a variable in my script like this results in the following error.

```
[float]$r=0.05
--or--
$r=0.05



  PS C:>get-mycmdlet

  cmdlet Get-mycmdlet at command pipeline position 1
  Supply values for the following parameters:
  (Type !? for Help.)
  myPropperty: $r
  Cannot recognize "$r" as a System.Single due to a format error.
  myProperty:
```

What is needed in my PS cmdlet to get it to accept my variables?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work just fine if you specify the parameter on the command line, i.e:

```
get-mycmdlet -MyProperty $r
```

I don't think that the interactive prompts accept variables.

Comment: yes that does work. I am not aware of that limitation about interactive prompts